Move to specific row in google sheet once a specific dropdown option is selected
the requried is once choose the year in the dropdown list, the sheet should move to a certin row in the sheet.
Ex: if i select 2021 in cell B1 the sheet will move to cell A14

I tried to search all related topics in stackoverflow, but it didn't help my case

You want to move the cursor to a given row based on the value selected in a dropdown.
There are many examples along these lines in StackOverflow but none that involve a dropdown so the following script is offered.
Comments

The script is named onEdit(e); a "Simple" trigger because the only activity is to move the cursor.

The script is automatically triggered by an edit to any cell so the logic needs a test to match a given sheet, given row and given column

(e) indicates use of Event Objects in the script

var rowValues = [[2020, 4], [2021, 14]] provides the target row for respective year numbers. There are many ways that this could have been done but this is one of the easiest. indexOf is used to find the matching year, and the relevant row

setActiveRange(range) Doc ref moves the cursor to the top left cell in the range as the current cell.



function onEdit(e) {

  // Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e))// DEBUG display all event objects

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()

  // the tear values and associated row numbers
  var rowValues = [[2020, 4], [2021, 14]]

  // variables to Watch
  var sheet2Watch = "Sheet1"
  var row2Watch = 1
  var column2Watch = 2
  
  // Edited values
  var editedSheet = e.range.getSheet().getName()
  var editedRow = e.range.rowStart
  var editedCol = e.range.columnStart
  // the values are returned as strings, so convert the year from a string to an integer
  var editedValue = parseInt(e.value, 10);

  // test for matching values
  if ((sheet2Watch !== editedSheet) || (row2Watch !== editedRow) || (column2Watch !== editedCol)){
    // No match, do nothing
    // Logger.log("No Match") // DEBUG
  }
  else{
    // the sheet, Row and Column match  
    // Logger.log("Match") // DEBUG

    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheet2Watch)
    // find the selected year in the first column of the rowValues
    var yearIndex = rowValues.map(r => r[0]).indexOf(editedValue)
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: Index = "+yearIndex)
    // get the row value from the RowValues
    var targetRow = rowValues[(yearIndex)][1]
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: target row = "+targetRow)
    // set the target range 
    var range = sheet.getRange(targetRow,1);
    // make the active cel using the target range
    sheet.setActiveRange(range);

  }
}


